# Startup Parameters within the Script?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, sta

I have a script that needs to run in single-threaded mode, and I currently start it up with the `-sta` parameter with a batch. Is it possible to run the script in `-sta` mode only executing the Script? I thought about moving the whole script into one function and execute this function in single-threaded mode.

Is that possible? I don't want to give out a batch file and my ps1.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you were to get PowerGUI and put the script into this, you would be able to package the PS1 file into an exe file which can just be executed like a normal program.

Once PowerGUI is installed you can do this from Tools, Complile Script.